# Does a plural noun that doesn't refer to a nonspecific or generic noun need to have a definite article?

Tags: definite-article, determiners

For instance, "processes that wish to use a resource will be blocked" vs "the processes that wish to use a resource will be blocked".
Do they have any differences?

Comment: No article is required in your example. Indeed, using *the* would be wrong, sounding to a native speaker overly restrictive, and perhaps inspiring those addressed to wonder, “**What** processes that wish to use a resource?” One **could** correctly say, “**A** process that wish**es**…” but normally one would use no determiner at all: the implied and understood meaning is “Any process that wishes…”

Comment: There's an implied determiner / quantifier in OP's example - ***any*** or ***all***, depending on whether one wishes to imply that feasibly there might be ***no*** processes that wish to use the resource. Note that ***any*** works with singular OR plural ***processes***, but ***all*** can only be (optionally) included with the plural noun.

Answer (score 1):

The bare plural noun can mean "any and every instance" of the noun. The bare plural noun is indeterminate.

> Processes that fail midstream because the cloud server has suddenly dropped the connection are advised to use transactions and implement retry logic.

Adding the definite article, "*the* processes", is not necessary and does not make any practical difference when there is a defining relative clause.